# wordpress custom plugin post time changer

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

I wrote my first wordpress plugin here's the code:

```
    <?php
// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

define( 'PLUGIN_NAME_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin activation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-post-time-changer-activator.php
 */
function activate_post_time_changer() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-post-time-changer-activator.php';
    Post_Time_Changer_Activator::activate();
}

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin deactivation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-post-time-changer-deactivator.php
 */
function deactivate_post_time_changer() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-post-time-changer-deactivator.php';
    Post_Time_Changer_Deactivator::deactivate();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_post_time_changer' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_post_time_changer' );

/**
 * The core plugin class that is used to define internationalization,
 * admin-specific hooks, and public-facing site hooks.
 */
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-post-time-changer.php';

/**
 * Begins execution of the plugin.
 *
 * Since everything within the plugin is registered via hooks,
 * then kicking off the plugin from this point in the file does
 * not affect the page life cycle.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
function run_post_time_changer() {

    $plugin = new Post_Time_Changer();
    $plugin->run();

}
run_post_time_changer();


add_action('admin_menu', 'PTC_setup_menu');

function PTC_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'Post Time Changer', 'PostTimeChanger', 'manage_options', 'post-time-changer', 'ptc_option_page' );
}
global $ptc_db_version;
$ptc_db_version = '1.0';


//install database table 
function ptc_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $ptc_db_version;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'concilium';

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        hours tinytext NOT NULL,
        minutes tinytext NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );

    add_option( 'ptc_db_version', $ptc_db_version );
}
//initial database data
function ptc_install_data() {
    global $wpdb;

    $hours = '6';
    $minutes = '12';

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'concilium';

    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array( 

            'hours' => $hours, 
            'minutes' => $minutes, 
        ) 
    );
}


function ptc_table_check(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'concilium';
$checktable = mysql_query('select 1 from' . $table_name );
if($checktable !== FALSE)
{
    ptc_install();
    echo "database installed!";
}else{
    ptc_update_data();
    echo "data upadated!";
}

}

//update data
function ptc_update_data(){
    global $wpdb;
    $hours = $_POST['hours'];
    $minutes = $_POST['minutes'];
    $table = 'wp_concilium';
    $rows = $wpdb->update( 
    $table, 
    array( 
        'hours' => $hours,  // string
        'minutes' => $minutes   // integer (number) 
    ), 
    array( 'ID' => 1 ), 
    array( 
        '%s',   // value1
        '%d'    // value2
    ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
}

function ptc_option_page(){
        ?>
            <div class="wrap">
            <h1>Post Time Changer</h1>
            <?php 
            global $wpdb;
            $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM wp_concilium");
            foreach ( $result as $print) {
                ?>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <form action="<?php ptc_update_data(); ?>" method="post">
            <?php settings_fields('plugin_options'); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections('plugin'); ?>


<!-- amount of time the post should be anticipated -->

set the amount of Hours you want your post to be anticipated <input name="hours" type="number" value="" /><br/>
set the amount of minutes you want your post to be anticipated <input name="minutes" type="number" value="" /><br/>
<tr>
                <td><h2>currently set to</h2></td>
                <td><?php echo $print->hours;?> hours</td>
                <td><?php echo $print->minutes;?> minutes</td>
            </tr><b/>
<!--save setting on the bottom -->
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="update" />
</form></div>
<?php
add_action('admin_init', 'plugin_admin_init');
function plugin_admin_init(){
register_setting( 'plugin_options', 'plugin_options', 'plugin_options_validate' );
add_settings_section('plugin_main', 'Main Settings', 'plugin_section_text', 'plugin');
add_settings_field('plugin_text_string', 'Plugin Text Input', 'plugin_setting_string', 'plugin', 'plugin_main');


}

}
```

the plugin update the database with the amount of hours and minutes that I want to anticipate the publication of my post so that the people can think I've published few hours before of the actual time.
the code is working properly exept for the fact that in the part of code:

```
             <tr>
                <td><h2>currently set to</h2></td>
                <td><?php echo $print->hours;?> hours</td>
                <td><?php echo $print->minutes;?> minutes</td>
            </tr><b/>
```

it doesn't show the correct time it's been saved in the database, but when I reload the page it shows the time saved, and here is another problem when I reload the database fields return to 0.

How can i fix this?